# Comparing field of a table to calculate another field using ArcPy cursor?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.5

How can I compare one field of a table to calculate another field? I have a table containing 'SL', 'Name' and 'Value' fields. I need to calculate the total value each name have. Example is shown in the picture below.
It will be great, if it would be Python script.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Coding questions here are expected to include code.  We don't expect perfection, just an honest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Just use the summary statistics tool the case field being your name field.

Answer (score 1):

`arcpy.Statistics_analysis(<in_table>, <out_table>, [['Name','SUM']])` will create a new table with the values you're looking for.